# Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableExtension+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[TElement]' violates the constraint of type 'TElement'

Tags: c#, azure, azure-functions

When creating an Azure Function that uses Azure Table Storage as an input binding and trying to retrieve multiple entities instead of just a single enntity I get the following error:

```
Error:
Function ($ScheduleTrigger) Error: Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host: Error indexing method 'Functions.myTimerTrigger'. Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host:  GenericArguments[0], 'Submission#0+Task', on  Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableExtension+TableToIQueryableConverter`1[     TElement]' violates the constraint of type 'TElement'. mscorlib: GenericArguments[0], 'Submission#0+Task', on 'Microsoft.Azure.WebJobs.Host.Tables.TableExtension+TableToIQueryableConverter`1    [TElement]' violates the constraint of type parameter 'TElement'.    
Session Id: f4a00564b4864fb3a131557dd45924c7    

Timestamp: 2017-09-05T07:48:09.738Z
```

The code I use for the, in this case, C# timer trigger is as follows:

```
using System;

public class Task
{
    public string PartitionKey { get; set; }
    public string RowKey { get; set; }
    public DateTime Timestamp { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, IQueryable<Task> inputTable, TraceWriter log)
{
    foreach (var task in inputTable) {
        log.Info($"Processing task '{task.Name}' at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
    log.Info($"Timer trigger executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've found the answer to the above myself, but since the error message didn't get me an answer quickly I figured I'd post and answer the question myself.

The error is caused because the model I used for my entity does not derive from EntityTable as described here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-table

Simply changing the code sample above to the following will fix the error:

```
using System;

public class MyInput : TableEntity
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public static async Task Run(TimerInfo myTimer, IQueryable<MyInput> inputTable, TraceWriter log)
{
    foreach (var item in inputTable) {
        log.Info($"Processing item '{item.Name}' at: {DateTime.Now}");
    }
    log.Info($"Timer trigger executed at: {DateTime.Now}");
}
```

Comment: They probably have something like `IQueryable<TEntity> where TEntity : TableEntity` in the code, then you get an error message since your entity type does not fulfill the constraint.

Comment: Did you mean to name your TableEntity class 'Task'?  That will conflict with the built-in System.Threading.Task.

Comment: @mike-s that was indeed a poor choice of naming. It was renamed in the actual code and for good measure I will change it here as well to make sure no one accidentally copies it.

Answer (score 1):

For an IQueryable<T>  binding, T must be a TableEntity.  Beware that binding to IQueryable ignores the other binding properties (partition key, row key, filter, take).

However, you're just using a foreach here, so you could do simpler bindings. 
We have a work item to bind directly to a T[] (where T has no constraints). https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk/issues/972 . Feel free to Upvote that if it'd be useful in your case.